# redis vs postgresql for wildcard search of large number of records

Tags: postgresql, redis

I have a list of over 100 million strings that essentially would look like a database table with single column and 100+ million rows.  I need to be able to do a wildcard search over that list.  For example, all strings that end with foo-- *foo.

I played with Mysql, but it takes way too long (for reasons that are obvious now).  I'm looking for an alternative.  Someone suggested Postgresql with a  trigram index, and I've been looking at Redis as well.

The total size of the data could fit in memory-- data set of 100 million records I'm currently playing with is around 2GB.  So, thought perhaps an in-memory database like Redis might work.  But, I don't have key-value pairs, just a list of 100+ million keys.  The Redis SCAN command seems like it would work, and I could just use a dummy value of some kind for each key (?).

I haven't looked into the Postgresql trigram mechanism yet, but was curious if anyone had advice as to which direction to look.  Or, some other alternative?

Comment: You should take a look at the redis search module https://github.com/RedisLabsModules/RediSearch which would allow you to perform better queries on your data.

Comment: A specialist tool like elasticsearch might be better in this case.

Comment: A trigram index is the only way to get an indexed search in Postgres for a `'%foo'` condition.